# How to update all in all conda environments?

Tags: shell, conda

Instead of manually typing `conda update -n envname --all` for every environment, How can I update them all at once?

Is there a better way than what I've come up with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the shell script I came up with.

- It gets the list of environments in `json` form.

  - Then uses `jq` to access just the `envs` portion of that `json`.
  - I'm iterating through this list... which is a list of paths.
- I modify each iteration by:

  - Slicing it to remove the `"` on either end.
  - Reversing it.
  - Splitting it on `/` and taking the first piece.
  - Undoing the reverse.
- This updates all in the environment, automatically saying yes (`-y`) when prompted, and suppressing extensive output (`-q`).

```bash
for var in $(conda env list --json | jq '.envs[]')
do
conda update -n $(echo ${var:1:-1} | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev) --all -y -q
done
```